# How to convert Elemental2 JsObject to Map<String, String>?

Tags: java, gwt

Looking for a way to convert Elemental2 `JsObject` to `Map<String, String>`:

```java
import elemental2.core.JsObject;

public static Map<String, String> jsObjectToMap(JsObject obj) {
    // code in question
}
```

Is there a more efficient way that just iterating and creating a new map (I'll post that as my own answer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using simple iteration and copying:

```java
import elemental2.core.JsObject;
import jsinterop.base.Js;
import jsinterop.base.JsPropertyMap;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public static Map<String, String> jsObjectToMap(JsObject obj) {
    Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    JsPropertyMap<Object> propMap = Js.asPropertyMap(obj);
    propMap.forEach(key -> {
        result.put(key, Objects.toString(propMap.get(key)));
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the keys are unique? Otherwise you will overwrite all but the last value for that key.

Comment: I believe all keys in JS objects are unique